# Need help parsing JSON feed with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

Having trouble pulling up data from the JSON feed using Jquery. Can somebody please help. Just trying to get the title from the "stories" array from now and work my way up. What am I doing wrong??

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Tell the function where the feed is located
  $.getJSON("http://www.sfarts.org/sfarts/jftemp/sfartsJSONAPI.cfc?method=getTenStoriesfixed&returnformat=JSON#sthash.jmTrJRUN.dpuf", function(data) {
    //Grab each of the "entries"
    $.each(data.stories, function(i,item){
      //Only grab "entries" 10 times
      if(i < 10){
        //Create the links and throw them
        //into the body of the page
        $("body").append("<p>"+item.title+"</p>");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Without seeing the JSON in question it's kind-of hard to say. You also have not described what's happening. Are there errors reported? Does it do something you don't expect, or not do something you do expect?

Comment: As I see it is `.TITLE`, not `.title`.

Comment: Also `.STORIES` and not `.stories`

Comment: Here's the feed. http://www.sfarts.org/sfarts/jftemp/sfartsJSONAPI.cfc?method=getTenStoriesfixed&returnformat=JSON#sthash.jmTrJRUN.dpuf       Does anyone know how I can use JSONP to simply pull out IMAGEPATH? I can figure out the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to include jQuery first:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then, you'll need to configure cross domain policies to allow receipt of data from another domain. Here's the top document covering that info on stackoverflow: [jQuery AJAX cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

Comment: Another good article about handling cross domain: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/